# Magento 2 exception.log error: GraphQL\\Error\\Error(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist

Tags: magento, magento2

We see the following error in our Magento 2.4.6 exception.log and really can't figure why we get this error. Any one seen this before?

Best regards,
Jesper

```
[2023-10-26T09:02:19.026058+00:00] main.ERROR: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again.
```

GraphQL (2:31)
1: query ($productId: Int!) {
2:                               productUpdate(
^
3:                                 productId: $productId
{"exception":"[object] (GraphQL\Error\Error(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. at /var/www/site.dk/public_html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Error/Error.php:155)
[previous exception] [object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. at /var/www/site.dk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:326)"} []
[2023-10-26T09:02:19.538585+00:00] main.ERROR: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again.

GraphQL (2:31)
1: query ($productId: Int!) {
2:                               productUpdate(
^
3:                                 productId: $productId
{"exception":"[object] (GraphQL\Error\Error(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. at /var/www/site.dk/public_html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Error/Error.php:155)
[previous exception] [object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. at /var/www/site.dk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:326)"} []
[2023-10-26T09:02:23.060906+00:00] main.ERROR: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again.

Comment: Do you have some 3rd party extensions installed? There is no productUpdate graphql query in Magento 2.4.6 out of the box. I think this must be an added extension.